# NestJS - serving static files locally and on Azure website

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, nestjs, multer

I have a simple application that allows a user to upload a photo and then retrieve that photo via a folder location.

Here is my controller and `multerOptions`.

```
@Controller('api/setup')
export class SetupController {
    @Post('upload')
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('image', multerOptions))
    async uploadPhoto(@UploadedFile() image, @Req() req) {
        if (req.fileValidationError)
            throw new UnsupportedMediaTypeException('Invalid file type');
        return "Success";
    }

    @Get('photo/:photoName')
    async servePhoto(@Param('photoName') photo, @Res() res) {
        res.sendFile(photo, { root: 'photos' });
    }
}

////////////////////////////
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype !== 'image/png') {
        req.fileValidationError = true;
        cb(null, false);
    } else {
        cb(null, true);
    }
};

export const multerOptions = {
    storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './photos',
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            return cb(null, 'photo.png');
        },
    }),
    fileFilter: fileFilter,
};
```

When running this server code locally, a `photos` directory is created for me like so:
(I'm not sure why it's necessarily created there. The setup controller is in `/src/Setup` as you can see.)

```
├── Server
│   ├── photos
|   |   ├── photo.png
│   └── src
|   |   ├── Setup
|   |   |   ├── setup.controller.ts // this is my controller file
```

In any case, this all seems to work locally. I can upload an image and when navigating to `http://localhost:8080/api/setup/photo/photo.png`, I can see the photo.

However, when I deploy this onto an Azure website, I get a bit confused as to where the photo is being stored.

When building the Server, NestJS generates a `dist` folder which I copy over to my Azure website.

```
├── wwwroot
│   ├── photos
|   |   ├── photo.png
│   └── dist
|   |   ├── Setup
|   |   |   ├── setup.controller.js // this is my built controller file
|   |   |   ├── setup.controller.js.map
```

Now after uploading a photo and navigating to the website: 'http://myAzureWebsite.com/api/setup/photo/photo.png', I can no longer see that photo. I presume it has something to do with a path issue but I can't seem to figure out where to properly create the folder and reference photo.png.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your static files (in your case photos directory) under the main file. something like that:

```
app.use('/img', express.static(join(__dirname, 'path/.../photos')));
```

PS: in **multerOptions**, "destination" option gives you the ability to choose where your photos should be saved. and it's recommended to serve/save static files from the project directory root.